# child_id and parent_id addition of values in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can I solve this question in python pandas, I was asked this in an interview.

```
   id  value  p_id
0   1     10   2.0
1   2     20   NaN
2   3     30   4.0
3   4     40   5.0
4   5     50   NaN
```

This is the output which I require:

```
   id  value  p_id  vsum
0   1     10   2.0  30.0
1   2     20   NaN  20.0
2   3     30   4.0  120.0
3   4     40   5.0  90.0
4   5     50   NaN  50.0
```

Comment: `df['v_sum'] = df['value'] * df['v_id'].fillna(1)`. And for next time, please ask questions as in the instructions.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please consider checking out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that users have an easier time to understand the problem and can answer your questions.

Comment: In the third record the value of v_sum should be 120 not 70 because 30+40+50 which is #id's parent_id is 4 and 4's parent is 5 so everything should be summed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want:

```
df['v_sum']=df[::-1].groupby(df['p_id'].shift().isna().cumsum())['value'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   id  value  p_id  v_sum
0   1     10   2.0     30
1   2     20   NaN     20
2   3     30   4.0    120
3   4     40   5.0     90
4   5     50   NaN     50
```

Comment: In the third record the value of v_sum should be 120 not 70 because 30+40+50 which is #id's parent_id is 4 and 4's parent is 5 so everything should be summed up

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution if you're open to approaching this as a network/graph problem.

We'll create a [`DiGraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html) using the [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) package and sum the values of the [`decendants`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.descendants.html) for each `id`:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df.dropna(subset=['p_id']),  # we're only interested in id's with descendants
    source='id',
    target='p_id',
    create_using=nx.DiGraph)     # Directed Graph

# You can inspect this graph using the following
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[image]

```
# Create a cumulative sum of descendents values for each id
descendants = {n: df.loc[df['id'].isin(nx.descendants(G, n)), 'value'].sum() for n in G.nodes}

df['v_sum'] = df['id'].map(descendants) + df['value']
```

[out]

```
   id  value  p_id  v_sum
0   1     10   2.0     30
1   2     20   NaN     20
2   3     30   4.0    120
3   4     40   5.0     90
4   5     50   NaN     50
```

Comment: In the third record the value of v_sum should be 120 not 70 because 30+40+50 which is #id's parent_id is 4 and 4's parent is 5 so everything should be summed up

Comment: @Raghavendra ahhh I see, I've updated my answer, approaching the problem from a network point of view. Hope it helps